# Finding a,b of elipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, locus

Given $x^{2}+y^{2}=R^{2}$, so that we multiply every $x$ by $a$ and every $y$ by $b$, $(a>b)$

And the distance between the focuses  of this locus is $48R$, and the area of the rhombus which Vertices are on the $x$-axis and $y$-axis ,bounded in that locus, is $350$.

Need to find $a,b$.

So i find that the locus is $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=R^{2}$ 
and tried to calculate by distance formula
but got a very messy calculation.

Would be glad to see any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first statement *does not* lead to the equation for the ellipse that you give later, so I will pass over that and simply use the standard-form equation, $$\frac{x^2}{(aR)^2} + \frac{y^2}{(bR)^2} = 1 .$$

This tells us that the ellipse is centered on the origin with semi-horizontal axis $aR$ and semi-vertical axis $bR$; the requirement that $ a > b $ makes the result unique because the major (focal) axis of the ellipse must then be "horizontal" (not having this inequality would also permit a "vertical" ellipse of the same size).

The area of the rhombus is four times the area of a triangle with its legs being the semi-horizontal and semi-vertical axes, so we have $$4 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot aR \cdot bR  =  2abR^2  =  350  \Rightarrow  abR^2  =  175 .$$

The focal distance  $c$ of a focus from the center of the ellipse is given by $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$ . The separation of the foci is then $2c = 48R$ , so we may write $$4c^2 = 4(a^2 - b^2) = 48^2R^2  \Rightarrow   a^2 - b^2  =  12 \cdot 48 \ R^2 $$

$$\Rightarrow  a^2 - (\frac{175}{aR^2})^2  =  12 \cdot 48 \ R^2 . $$

Multiplying through by $a^2$ will give us a quadratic equation in $a^2$:

$$a^4 - (12 \cdot 48 \ R^2) \cdot a^2 - (\frac{175^2}{R^4})  =  0  $$

$$ \Rightarrow a^2 =  \frac{(12 \cdot 48 \ R^2) + \sqrt{(12 \cdot 48 \ R^2)^2 + 4 \cdot (\frac{175^2}{R^4})}}{2}  = (288) \cdot \left[1 + \sqrt{1 +  (\frac{175}{288 \cdot R^4})^2} \right] \cdot R^2 ,$$

where we have discarded the "negative radical" solution from the quadratic formula, since the radical is larger than $12 \cdot 48 R^2$ alone.  We can then insert this into our earlier relation $b^2 =  (\frac{175}{aR^2})^2 $.

Note that we are not given enough information to find specific values for all three variables; the proportions of the ellipse are determined, but the size of the ellipse is determined by the choice for $R$ .